# Croppie: image bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

I'm using https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie to crop images:

```
var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
            viewport: {
                width: 640,
                height: 640
            },
            boundary: {
                width: 640,
                height: 640
            },
            showZoom: false
        });

        basic.croppie('bind', {
            url: 'image.jpg'
        });
```

I need a resulting image size of 640*640 and I'm only using image that are bigger than 640*640, this works perfectly if I set the result to

```
 basic.croppie('result', {
                type: 'canvas',
                size: 'viewport'
            }).then(function (src) {
                window.open(src);
            });
```

How could I solve this on a mobile screen (with a screen width of like 320px)? The resulting image still has to be 640*640 and has to be the image the user actually sees while cropping (preview). 
I tried changing the `viewport` or the `boundary` parameters but the resulting image differs from the one the user sees while cropping (preview).

TLDR: How can I crop images, where both the original image and the cropped image are bigger than the screen width?

Answer (score 5):

This might help you-

```
basic.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: { width: 640, height: 640 }
        }).then(function (src) {
            window.open(src);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved by using a different plugin: http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: I'm also looking for an easier to understand script. I seems as though this is possible with croppie, judging by the issue comments, but the documentation and examples are poor and out of the box it isn't a responsive script.